# Reversal of cross-linking in ChIP-seq

Tags: molecular-genetics, protein-binding, protocol

Chromatin immunoprecipitation (ChIP) is a type of immunoprecipitation experimental technique used to investigate the interaction between proteins and DNA in the cell. A summary of the protocol for ChIP is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatin_immunoprecipitation). Briefly, the steps are:

1. DNA and associated proteins on chromatin in living cells or tissues are crosslinked;
2. The DNA-protein complexes are  sheared into ~500 bp DNA fragments by sonication or nuclease digestion;
3. Cross-linked DNA fragments associated with the protein(s) of interest are selectively immunoprecipitated from the cell debris using an appropriate protein-specific antibody;
4. The associated DNA fragments are purified and their sequence is determined.

After step 3 (immunoprecipitation of the protein-DNA complex), it is my understanding that the protein–DNA cross-link is reversed and proteins are removed by digestion with proteinase K.

Can anyone tell me if during this step the DNA at site of cross-linking is included in further sequencing step or is washed away with the protein itself?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I've tidied up the question a bit - hope the edits are okay.

Comment: So you want to know if in the crosslink reversal step the DNA gets lost?

Comment: Yes. More specifically at the point where protein & DNA is attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the crosslink reversal step, you still have some DNA connected to protein fragments.

So at that step, instead of doing a normal DNA purification, we also need to use a [phenol-chloroform extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenol%E2%80%93chloroform_extraction) or special columns to seperate DNA from protein fragments.

Thermofisher usually gives [really good explanations](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/chromatin-ip-chip-assays.html) too.

Please let me know if I didn't understand the question correctly! :)